# Is there a way to have lambda function added to a map at compile time or before main even though it's within local scope in c++?

Tags: c++

`#define callback(id, func) std::pair<decltype(id), decltype(func)>(id, func)`
The question sounds tricky. What I want to do is to build a id-function mapping dispatcher without user doing it at global scope. When the user writes `objectA.send(b, callback(id, []{}))` like this inside any function, the lambda expression is somehow registered into a global map at compile time or before main function so that I can lookup it through the id later. I want to build a library that construct the lookup map without user pay any attention to the map. The reason why I think it can be done at compile time is that if the id and the lambda funcion are given staticly before run time, a lookup map with constant value can be deduced at compile time theoretically

Comment: Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I want to provide an interface like this `objectA.send(b, callback(id, []{}))`. I want to make a storage like map to store id-lambda mapping without user taking much difficulties calling other interface. Right now I am stucking in the latter part wondering if there is any mechanism allowing me to to that

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a Factory to be a singleton that creates the lambdas, and records them in a `std::map` as well.

A different file, `Constructible.h`, will contain functions that set up that map, and perform searches into it.

A `.cpp` file, `Registration.cpp`, will contain calls to the function (in  `Constructible.h`) which sets up the map with the allowed lambdas you want.
You can update the list of allowed lambdas when needed.

The file will have to compile along `main.cpp`. If they are in the same folder this is easy and automatic on most IDEs.
The `.cpp` file is wrapped in an anonymous `namespace` in order to shield it from users tampering with it.

In short:

- 1. `Registration.cpp` #includes `Constructible.h`.
- 2. `Registration.cpp` sets global variables of type `Helper`(defined in `Constructible.h`).
- 3. Construction of the first `Helper` object instantiates the `Factory`.
- 4. All `Helper`s are registered with the `Factory`.
- 5. `main.cpp` program can then execute its tasks smoothly.

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <Constructible.h>
#include <Factory.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <Lambda.h>

int main()
{
    std::string name = "this_lambda";
    double a_number = 57.1;
    Lambda* ptr_to_func = Factory::Instance().CreateLambda(name, a_number); 
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

`Lambda.h`:

```
#include <functional>
// here you define your lambdas, for instance:
using Lambda = std::function<double (double)>;
using AnotherLambda = std::function<double (int)>;

Lambda my_lambda = 
[](double x){
    return x + 1.23;
};

AnotherLambda my_lambda_2 = 
[](int x){
    return x / 2;
};
```

`Factory.h`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <Lambda.h>

class Factory  
{
public:

    typedef Lambda* (*CreateLambdaFunction)(double); 
    // insert the parameters of your lambda as arguments above,
    // here we have double

    static Factory& Instance();
    void Register(std::string, CreateLambdaFunction);
    Lambda* CreateLambda(std::string a_id, double input);
    ~Factory(){};

private:
    std::map<std::string, CreateLambdaFunction> MyCreatorFunctions;
    Factory(){}
    Factory(const Factory&) = default;
    Factory& operator=(const Factory&) = default;
    Factory(Factory&&) = default;
    Factory& operator=(Factory&&) = default;
};

void Factory::Register(string a_id, CreateLambdaFunction CreatorFunction)
{
     MyCreatorFunctions.insert(pair<string,CreateLambdaFunction>(a_id, CreatorFunction));
}

Lambda* Factory::CreateLambda(string a_id, double input)
{
    map<string, CreateLambdaFunction>::const_iterator 
                                i = MyCreatorFunctions.find(a_id);
    
    if  (i == MyCreatorFunctions.end())
    {
        std::cout << a_id << " is an unknown object\n";
        return NULL;
    }

    return (i->second)(input);
}

Factory& Factory::Instance()
{
    static Factory myFactory;
    return myFactory;
}
```

`Constructible.h`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Lambda.h>
#include <Factory.h>
#include <string>

template <class T>   // T a type in the Lambda class hierarchy
class Helper
{
public:
    Helper(std::string);
    static Lambda* Create(double);
};

template <class T>
Lambda* Helper<T>::Create(double input)
{
    return new T(input);
}

template <class T>
Helper<T>::Helper(std::string id)
{
    Factory& MyFactory = Factory::Instance();
    MyFactory.Register(id, Helper<T>::Create);
}
```

`Registration.cpp`:

```
#include <Constructible.h>

namespace
{
     Helper<Lambda> RegisterLambda("this_lambda");
 
     // another lambda
     Helper<AnotherLambda> RegisterAnotherLambda("another_lambda");
}
```

Comment: This is really nice a fragment of code and thanks for answering. However, I can come accross a similar solution like this. What I want to simplify is the process of having user to register the lambda callback like this. I want to make it possible that when calling a send function and passing an object or passing #define stuff or passing alias stuff, this registration map can be automatically generated at compile time or the registration happens at startup of the programe before main. This sounds tricky and I don't expect getting a solution. Just ask to know if there's some hacky way doing this

Comment: The idea of having this functionality is that I want to simplify the process of registering callback for a remote procedure call. The reason for having this registration map generated at compile time or before program startup is to make sure a callback function can be revoked even though the program crashes (i.e. coredump or unexpectable exit)as long as the reply packet can be retrieve somewhere.

Comment: @GuohaoYi Ok, so basically you wish to have the program automatically generating, at the start, what (in my code above) I called the `Registration.cpp` file. The solution I came up with in the above is: the programmer *manually* fills that file with the lambdas he wants to use. Then the Factory automatically generates the lambdas afterwards when they are needed.

Comment: @GuohaoYi For the compiler to perform this task automatically (instead of having the user fill the `Registration.cpp` file), the program would require a parser module that, at compile time, scans the program for lambdas, identifies them as such by their syntax, assigns each of them a key, and adds them (as values) to a `map`. You'll have to check parser libraries as it may be complicated and time-consuming to write one yourself, especially if you have never done it. Try to edit your question by adding a 'parser' tag, if it exists, maybe you'll get people with the know-how in here to reply.

Comment: @GuohaoYi also a 'Factory pattern' tag would be helpful in attracting the right people, if it exists.

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem. It seems to me that there is no such function for the time being and if I try the approach you mentioned I may also need to provide a tool to generate the code, which I think could be done through llvm, but this may still require the users to do something to set up the tool generating the code in a makefile or cmakelists.txt or other compile tool. I think this gets more complicated and it does not contribute to ease the use of a library like that. At leaset I know that it's not possible for the compiler to do that right now. Thanks a lot